# Mac OS 10.9 asks for MAS password after reboot

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mavericks

I've recently installed Mac OS 10.9 (fresh installation) on a Macbook Pro Mid 2010 and restored my user folder via a Time Machine backup. If I restart my Mac, my Wallpaper gets reverted to default and I have to enter the MAS password for almost every Application I want to start (which I've bought via MAS, of course).

Is there a reason why my Wallpaper gets reverted and I have to enter my MAS password if I want to start a MAS Application after every reboot? Is there a problem with permissions on my home folder?

Comment: I'm maybe not fully awake yet... But what is MAS ? I have been a Mac user for years, but I have never heard of this.

Comment: Mac App Store (MAS)

Comment: Aha... We just call it the AppStore around here. I just never saw that abbreviation before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a virus, however it may be a permission error, which means that the application is probably not able to write the password (or wallpaper) to disk.

If it is a permission error, it is easily fixed
Go to Disk Utility, this can be found in your applications folder under Utilities.
Click on your disk, (the second one below the technical name, it usually says Macintosh HD) and click the First Aid tab, you may need to click verify disk permissions before you click the Repair Disk Permissions button. Depending on what is causing the problem, you may need to also click verify disk and then repair disk.
Hope I helped!